# Conditional VAE ignoring conditional variables

Tags: deep-learning

I am training a conditional VAE on a timeseries datase. Although my model is training well as evident by the small training and validation loss. however while generating samples, my model completely ignores the conditional variables and it looks like that it only generates samples based on the random inout z. I have not been able to figure out what the issue is here. has anyone ever faced this issue?